# Constraint NSString in method signature to a set of already defined constant

Tags: objective-c

I am not trying to achieve anything particular, just experimenting with objective-c.

I have a method that take a NSString. Recently I added a set of NSString constant.
Very much like enum, where in the signature you can refer to the enum name, I am wondering if there's a way at compile time to group NSString const to a common name for being put in method signature, without coding a set of 'if-else' within the method itself.

I mean, this is what I am actually doing:

```
static *const MyConstOne = @"const1";
static *const MyConstTwo = @"const2";
static *const MyConstThree = @"const3";

-(void)myMethod:(NSString*)value {

  if(value==MyConst1) {
    // do something...
  }

  // do other check...

  // if I am here value does not correspond to any const
}
```

and this would be the desired method, which is obviously wrong:

```
-(void)myMethod:(MyConst*)const;
```